# Creating a JSON object from Javascript array

Tags: javascript, json

So for each checkbox selected, I am getting the associated id and depending on values there deducing the node values, which is working fine. The problem I am facing is creating a proper javascript object with values from all checkboxes.

Here's the function,

```
function finlizeJParams()
                    {
                        var jsonOutput=[];
                        var array =  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function(){ 

                            var str=this.id;

                            var data=[];
                            var objID=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("c_")+2,str.lastIndexOf("_n_"));
                            var objName=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_n_")+3,str.lastIndexOf("_p_"));
                            var objParentID=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_p_")+3,str.lastIndexOf("_pn_"));
                            var objParentName=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_pn_")+4);

                            data['ItemID']=objID;
                            data['ItemName']=objName;
                            data['ItemParentID']=objParentID;
                            data['ItemParentName']=objParentName;
                            jsonOutput.push(data)

                            return jsonOutput;
                        }).get()

                        JSON.stringify(array);
                    }
```

This seems to be working as I am getting arrays when I try to print it on console, See below

```
0: Array[0]
    ItemParentName: "Fruit"
    ItemParentID: "7"
    ItemID: "8"
    ItemName: "Apple"
1: Array[0]
    ItemParentName: "Fruit"
    ItemParentID: "7"
    ItemID: "9"
    ItemName: "Orange"
```

However, if I do a *JSON.stringify(jsonOutput)*, I get empty arrays [[],[]]? What am I doing wrong? Also, how can I group these array by parentID/Name and then convert to a JSON object?

Comment: I can't immediately see the bug, but you seem to be confusing several approaches to the problem: you're using `.map()` (transform one array to another), but not actually returning anything from the callback, so it's the same as if you did `.each` (loop over an array with no explicit result); and I've no idea what that `.get()` is doing on the end there.

Comment: Yeah, somehow messed it up trying to solve the issue. Code updated now.

Comment: You're still mixing up mapping a function over the array with looping over it with an external accumulator: `jsonOutput` is global to all iterations of the array, and you're adding to it on each loop; so you'll add 1 item the 1st time around, 2 on the 2nd, 3 on the 3rd, etc. Either use `.each` and keep `jsonOutput` as your accumulator (drop the `var array =`) or use `.map` and just return `data` each time (drop all references to `jsonOutput`).

Comment: Actually, it's worse than I thought: by returning the same object each time, you end up adding multiple references to the same object, which jQuery only flattens at the end, so the resulting array for 3 items contains the processed version of those 3 items, repeated 3 times.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the repetition as I wasn't getting the output properly, still a silly mistake to make.Fixed it removing the 'var array ='. The code worked by following @Quentin answer below and your advise helped fix the loop. Can you also give a hint on how can I group these items under parent id/name? I am trying but can use some guide in the right direction.

Comment: When trying to "group" data in JS, there is another important difference between an array and an object: an array has defined order, but automatically set keys; an object has keys which you decide, but no defined order. If the order of categories doesn't matter, then a structure like `cats = { 'cat1': [item1, item2], 'cat2': [item3, item4] }` will work; if you need the categories to be in order, it needs to be more like `cats = [ { 'name': 'cat1', 'items': [item1, item2], 'name': 'cat2', 'items': [item3, item4] } ]`. Try adding to some structures by hand before putting the code into the loop.

Comment: Eugh, just noticed that I typo'd in that last sample; it should read `cats = [ { 'name': 'cat1', 'items': [item1, item2] }, { 'name': 'cat2', 'items': [item3, item4] } ]`, since the intention is for `cats` to be an array containing two objects, with each object holding another array in its `items` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are treating an array as a plain object.

While arrays inherit from objects, they are designed for numerical indexed, sequential data and only properties with numerical values will be included when you pass them through `JSON.stringify`.

If you want to use named keys, then use an object (`{}`), not an array (`[]`).

```
var data={};
```